# Error getting the coverage report with rewire / cross-env

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, istanbul, nyc

I'm trying to get the coverage report using nyc and it works well if I'm not using the cross-env plugin.

`cross-env NODE_ENV=test nyc mocha --ui bdd --reporter spec --colors --require babel-core/register tests --recursive`

executing this command the code coverage won't run properly and the result is the following:

```
 31 passing (1s)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

However if I run this `nyc mocha --ui bdd --reporter spec --colors --require babel-core/register tests --recursive` it will work as expected.

```
---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File                 |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files            |    79.45 |    64.29 |    35.71 |    84.62 |                   |
 constants           |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  index.js           |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 db                  |    77.05 |    64.29 |    33.33 |    83.02 |                   |
---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

The issue is that I need to set the env variable in order to use the rewire plugin that allows me to run the test properly (indeed, most of the test are failing because of that).

This is my .bebelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["istanbul", "babel-plugin-rewire"]
    }
  }
}
```

**note**:  I think the issue is related to the babel-plugin-rewire. Indeed, even removing the *cross-env* and placing the plugins collection in the root will give me the same empty coverage result.

Comment: Does moving the order help?

Comment: no, I've tried it already

Comment: See if this project works for you? https://github.com/jseminck/karma-rewire-istanbul-example. if so try to use same package version. Also go through this https://github.com/istanbuljs/babel-plugin-istanbul/issues/22

Comment: Yes I already saw the issue in github and that's not my case anyway. Same for the project sample. Again the problem is combining these two plugins together. If I use either one or the other will work.

Comment: Then provide a minimal git repo one can use to reproduce this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution on this issue playing around the babel configuration file and the plugins. To avoid this case would be better to use the last env preset. I also [created a repo](https://github.com/mirgj/es6-rewire-nyc) that reproduce the error and has a readme similar to this post.

### With rewire/cross-env

Running the test using the default commands (that use rewire and cross-env) will generate an empty coverage report:

```
npm run test
```

this command will execute only the tests and both of them will pass

```
npm run test:cov
```

this will execute the previous `test` script but will add the coverage report, which will result empty

```
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

### Without rewire/cross-env

removing `cross-env NODE_ENV=test` from the test script will avoid to load rewire and will generate a correct coverage. The side effect is that the test that use the rewire will fail.

```
npm run test2
```

will run the script without `cross-env`, so babel will not load the rewire plugin and so one test will fail.

```
npm run test:cov2
```

this command will use the previous `test2` script and generate the coverage. In this case the coverage report will be generated correctly.

```
------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File              |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files         |    64.29 |      100 |    54.55 |    66.67 |                   |
 src              |       75 |      100 |       60 |    85.71 |                   |
  a-dependency.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  a-module.js     |       60 |      100 |        0 |       75 |                 6 |
 tests            |       60 |      100 |       50 |       60 |                   |
  test.js         |       60 |      100 |       50 |       60 |... 23,24,26,27,28 |
------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

but its not correct due the missing rewire plugin.

### babelrc (es2015)

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["istanbul", "rewire"]
    }
  }
}
```

this is the babel configuration file used in the solution. Removing `rewire` plugin from the plugin collection will generate and empty coverage with `npm run test:cov` but not with `npm run test:cov2` (which is not using cross-env).

If I modify the babelrc in this way

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": ["istanbul", "rewire"]
}
```

both `npm run test:cov` (with cross-env) and `npm run test:cov2` (without cross-env). Will generate an empty result.

If I remove both the plugins

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

both command (with and without cross-env) will generate a coverage result (partial, since one test will fail)

Removing only `istanbul` from the plugin collection will generate a full coverage file and this would be the result (as expected)

```
------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File              |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files         |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 src              |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  a-dependency.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  a-module.js     |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 tests            |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  test.js         |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

### babelrc (env)

After going across this issues around the previous `es2015` preset, I moved to the `env` one. Installing it with `npm install babel-preset-env --save-dev` then I've modified my babelrc in this way.

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "node": "current"
      }
    }]
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["istanbul", "rewire"]
    }
  }
}
```

In this case `npm run test` works properly and `npm run test:cov` will generate a correct coverage report. And there will be no issue with cross-end or rewire.

### conclusion

Somehow both rewire and cross-env are creating issue if combined with babel when using the `es2015` preset. To generate the report with this preset apparenttly is sufficient to remove `istanbul` from the babel plugins and use only rewire (it will work well also with cross-env in this case).

I rather suggest to upgrate to the `env` preset and use the babel plugins as suggested (unless it create other issue to your project)

### env

```
> node --version
v9.4.0
> npm --version
5.6.0
>ver
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.309]
```

Same behavior has been observed on MacOS